# How can I take date values in a table row and convert those date values in to new columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I'd like to convert the dates that are in table rows in to table columns. So I'd like to take this output:

```
Name      | Date     | Consumption
Business A|2021-01-01|12
Business B|2021-01-01|15
Business C|2021-01-01|18
Business A|2021-02-01|10
Business B|2021-02-01|14
Business C|2021-02-01|13
Business A|2021-03-01|23
Business B|2021-03-01|21
Business C|2021-03-01|19
```

And turn it in to this output:

```
Name      | Jan-21 | Feb-21 | Mar-21
Business A|12      |10      |23
Business B|15      |14      |21
Business C|18      |13      |19
```

I'd like to use python and pandas to do it, but I'm very new to pandas and haven't really used it before. This data is stored in a postgresql database.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly convert your values of 'Date' column via `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%b-%y')
```

Finally use `pivot_table()` method:

```
df=df.pivot_table(index='Name',columns=['Date'],values='Consumption')
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Unfortunately it's not allowing me to use unstack() method because "the index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".

Comment: Updated answer...Kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's perfect! Now I just have to figure out how to keep this structure, but also include all my other columns I need for my view.